# I don't have a negative posting history. Why have I been banned?

Tags: discussion, support

I've come here a few times in the past year hoping to ask a question only to be reminded:

[image]

I dont recall deleting bad questions (and dont have the rep to see my deletions), and I've been using Stack Exchange for many years, paying attention to Meta, creating and reading Meta questions asking best practices, and while I definitely can recall a few guilty Stack Overflow questions where I was asking something too broad out of desperation to solve a confusing problem, I think my activity on SE is pretty mindful of quality overall.

Can someone with enough rep remind me what horrible deleted question lurking in my past here is the culprit of my permanent ban from the site?

[My history looks otherwise pretty ok.](https://superuser.com/users/227640/j-todd?tab=questions) Not great, lots of questions with no upvotes, but only 1 downvoted question of 11 total.

Comment: Your full post history is 24 questions of which 13 are deleted. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSeG0.jpg Deleted questions past a certain age [are not visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217169/how-do-i-view-my-old-deleted-questions) but may contribute to a ban. Some of the questions contributing may not have been "bad" but just got ignored and neither positively nor negatively received. At a glance at least a couple of questions in the distant past were actively off topic.

Comment: From [why are questions no longer being accepted from my account](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans) "If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question."

Answer (score 3):

> I don't recall deleting bad questions (and don't have the rep to see my deletions)

You have posted 24 questions, 13 of which have been deleted.

Your question scores are +5 (for the positive questions) and -12 (for the negative questions) so -7 net.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/945390/is-my-internet-connection-deliberately-shut-off-on-when-windows-8-needs-to-updat) was deleted by yourself and has a score of -7.

Deleted questions with negative votes:

- https://superuser.com/questions/945390/is-my-internet-connection-deliberately-shut-off-on-when-windows-8-needs-to-updat
- https://superuser.com/questions/1097026/how-do-i-turn-off-night-mode-on-gaming-youtube-com
- https://superuser.com/questions/792875/can-i-connect-a-surface-pro-2-mini-displayport-intel-hd-graphics-4400-windows
- https://superuser.com/questions/601279/building-a-computer-specifically-for-graphic-design-2k-budget

Comment: Thanks. I figured I deserved my ban. It was over a year ago so I guess I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont recall deleting bad questions (and dont have the rep to see my deletions), and I've been using Stack Exchange for many years, paying attention to Meta, creating and reading Meta questions asking best practices, and while

> I definitely can recall a few guilty Stack Overflow questions where I
> was asking something too broad out of desperation to solve a confusing
> problem, I think my activity on SE is pretty mindful of quality
> overall.

Are you question banned on Super User or Stack Overflow.  Question bans are separate to individual communities.  [You](https://superuser.com/users/227640/j-todd) certainly don’t have the best track record for asking questions here a Super User.  Asking clear precise questions is very important.

Question bans only happen after a continued verifiable pattern of asking questions that have been poorly received by the community.  The amount of questions that have to be poorly received is extremely variable, but question bans, never happen after only a handful of questions.

> Can someone with enough rep remind me what horrible deleted question lurking in my past here is the culprit of my permanent ban from the site?

You can access that yourself [here](https://superuser.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/227640) or at least the questions deleted in the last 60 days.

> Not great, lots of questions with no upvotes, but only 1 downvoted question of 11 total.

Every question that was closed and then deleted for inactivity, deleted by the moderators for quality reasons, or by yourself for any reason count against your ability to ask another question.

Your case is probably borderline to be honest.  I personally cannot search for your deleted questions, a moderator could perform that search, but question bans do not happen unless there is a pattern of poorly received questions.  **It appears you have asked 24 questions, 13 of those questions have been deleted, which means more than 50% of the questions you have asked have been deleted.**

You will be able to ask another question 6 months from when the ban started.   Your last question was on May, 6 months from that, would be around November 19th 2020.